# Android: Send Multiple sms on one click

Tags: android, sms, android-pendingintent, smsmanager

I am developing a sms sending application. the code is running fine. I am able to send sms from my application
For that i am using following code as :

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message, final int k){   
    String SENT = "SMS_SENT";
    String DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";

    Intent sentIntent = new Intent(SENT);
    Intent deliveredUntent = new Intent(DELIVERED);


    PendingIntent sentPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,sentIntent, 0);        
    PendingIntent deliveredPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,deliveredUntent, 0);

    //---when the SMS has been sent---
    sentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS sent "+k,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    //---when the SMS has been delivered---
    deliverReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
            switch (getResultCode()){
                case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;                      
            }           
        }
    };  

    try{
        registerReceiver(sentReceiver, new IntentFilter(SENT));
        registerReceiver(deliverReceiver, new IntentFilter(DELIVERED));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI); 
}
```

But now i want to **send sms to multiple numbers**. How can i do that. I searched on Google but not got satisfied answer.

Comment: use a for-each style loop to iterate through your mobile no. list, then send sms for the users. Something like this: for(phoneNumner:phoneNumbers){
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
}

Answer (score 4):

Simply Loop your list having multiple numbers and call sms.sendtextmessage  inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

### Try This Method it Work Perfectly for Me i hope it will help you

public void sendSMS(String number2[], String message) {

```
    for (int i = 0; i < number2.length; i++) {

        try {
            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
            smsManager.sendTextMessage(number2[i], null, message, null,
                    null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS Sent to" + " " + number2[1],
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            strNuum = strNuum + 1;
            btnNumber.setText("Sending " + strNuum + " " + "TO" + " "
                    + StringArrayNumber.length);
            edtName.setText("TO: " + number2[1]);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                }
            }, DISPLAY_TIME);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "SMS faild, please try again later!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```